# How to add keyboard shortcut for 'move focus to next window'

Tags: keyboard

It's bound to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

When I'm using the laptop's own keyboard it works fine,
but when I work with HHKB, <kbd>`</kbd> is just too far off. Can I add a secondary shortcut for the same `Move focus to next window`?

I'd like to do it with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done!

## Option 1: Create a new shortcut using Keyboard Maestro

*NOTE:*

- You can do what I've outlined here within the free trial of the app I believe, but I can't guarantee that'll always be the case.
- I am not affiliated with Keyboard Maestro or advertising for them, I just happen to know that you can create system shortcuts using their app.

### Steps:

1. Download and install the [Keyboard Maestro Trial](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)
2. Once you open the app an editor window will appear. On the left you'll see folders, in the central column you'll see a bunch of actions, and if you click on one you'll see the configuration options for each action
3. Click `+` on the bottom of the middle column to create a new action
   [image: Click on + at the bottom of the centre column to create a new action]
4. Give your action a name
5. **The important bit** Click on `New Trigger` and select `Hot Key Trigger`, then type ⌘ + esc to set it as the trigger.
6. **The other important bit** Click on the box the says 'No Action', this brings up an action picker on the left

   - Type 'Keystroke' into the search box
   - Drag the action called 'Type a keystroke' into the actions box
   - Click where it says 'Simulate Keystroke' and tap ⌘ + `
     [image: Select Type a keystroke for the action and then tap ⌘ + ']
7. You'll need to allow Keyboard Maestro to start on startup for it to monitor things in the background (right click on app icon -> Options -> Open at Login)
8. You now have an uncle called Robert

## Option 2: Change the System Shortcut (This doesn't add a secondary sadly)

1. Open `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard`

[image: Click on Keyboard]

2. Then select the `Shortcuts` tab at the top
3. Select `Keyboard` in the panel on the left
4. Click on the ⌘' symbol next to `Move focus to next window`
5. Type what you want it to be on your HHKB keyboard

[image: Click on the current keys for the shortcut]

Comment: Do you mean Robert?

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to keep the original shortcut and add another shortcut, so 2 shortcuts for one functionality.. is it possible?

Comment: You can do it with Keyboard Maestro! I'll edit the answer :)

Comment: @Avatron Yes I did mean Robert ‍♂️ Thanks for pointing it out! 